# How do I get Access Token using python for Google Beacon

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, google-beacon-platform

Very noob here coding oauth2 in python and Google Beacons. I know that oauth for Google is common but from all of the posts and Google searches, I cannot get anything to work.

I can get the beacon updates to work through Insomnia but I need to be able for the script itself to work (get access token and run code).

here is the script.

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("proximitybeacon.googleapis.com")

payload = " {\n  \"namespacedType\":\"com.google.nearby/en\",\n  \"data\":\"IHsNCiAgICAgInRpdGxlIjogIkl0IFdvcmtzISIsDQogICAgICJ1cmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9hZHZlcnRpc2luZ2Fyc2VuYWwuYml6Ig0KfQ==\"\n}"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'authorization': "Bearer [access token goes here]"
}

conn.request("POST", "/v1beta1/beacons/[beaconid]/attachments", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

The section [access token goes here] is where I'm stuck. If I put the access token supplied from Insomnia, the scripts work without issue until the token expires.

If anyone could help/point me towards a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

Tom